# Get excel cell value without UI update in Excel Addin Nodejs Api

Tags: excel, api, office-js, add-in, excel-addins

The key problem is that in our native web app we have an MVC architecture where the calculation engine, controller and UI are separate so when we recalculate we do not need to update UI ("expensive" operation).

As an add-in we are bound by excel API and we cannot find a way to run a recalculation without having to refresh the grid.

Even if we turn off UI update, when we need to get the value in a cell the UI is forced to update.

We call api `doNotUpdateScreenUntillNextSync()` but in order to get updated values we have to call `context.sync()` that will update the screen.

Any idea how to get cell value without UI update in excel.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the question.
Currently we only support context.sync level UI update suspend by Application.suspendScreenUpdatingUntilNextSync(). Details can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.application?view=excel-js-preview#suspendApiCalculationUntilNextSync__

Based on your description, maybe you can get the original value in a cell and calculate it then store the value in somewhere else. Then to update it until you want to refresh the UI.

And if you do want a Excel session level UI suspend API, please submit the requirement at Github. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the response. I follow your instruction and buffer the ranges and call context.sync() only once. 

But I have more than 24,000 range/cell buffered and when I call context.sync() in the end and excel literally hang and I see white space only. Even excel cells are not visible.

yes I do call app.suspendScreenUpdatingUntilNextSync()

Comment: can you share your gist to me to help repro and investigate the root cause? Thanks!

Comment: Here is the gist url use excel file added in comment section. https://gist.github.com/pkpatels/8b3bca619b39c78cb0bc09e18c8512c1 Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info. We will take a look and back to the thread when have progress.

Comment: We have discussed the issue and replied by mail. Thanks!