# Get the ultimate non-formula precedents of a cell in Excel Addin Nodejs Api

Tags: excel, api, office-js, add-in, excel-addins

The problem is we want to get the ultimate non-formula precedents of a cell. To be more clear precedents of precedents.

E.G.

```
A1      10
A2      =A1
A3      =A2
```

So for **A3** the precedent is **A2**, but the ultimate non-formula precedent is **A1** (there are no further precedents).

Right now we call `getDirectPrecedent()` and store a list. Then we call the same function for the list until we get non formula precedent cell.

Is there any optimised way to achieve this? Any native API function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Range.getPrecedents](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#getPrecedents__) API currently (April 9th, 2021) in preview. This returns all the precedents for a Range, not just the immediate, direct precedents.

While the API is not available in general availability, you can test it out in [Script Lab](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab?view=excel-js-preview). Here's a sample gist showing how to use the API with your sample data: https://gist.github.com/AlexJerabek/25c22d809e21c85175b81afd7b445198

Comment: Thank you @Alexander Jerabek. This save my day.  

I would appreciate if you can have a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66981426/get-excel-cell-value-without-ui-update-in-excel-addin-nodejs-api